# Слушатель выделения для ListView

Tags: android

Скажите, есть ли слушатель выделения элемента у `ListView`? Искал в гугле (на русском), но нашел только `onClickListener'ы` и тому подобные. Они реагируют на нажатие (когда палец отпустили), а мне нужно, чтобы слушатель реагировал на начало прикосновения к пункту списка, а потом на его отпускание. Есть такой слушатель предназначенный именно для `ListView` (а не `onTouch`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Полагаю, что ваше решение - onTouchListener. Может и момент нажатия поймать, и момент отпускания.

```
OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //something
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //something
        }
        return true;
    }
};

view.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: К сожалению, `onTouch` не то, что мне нужно (я его пробовал)...

Comment: @bukashka101 по вашей постановке вопроса подходит именно он. Поэтому объясните, в чём проблема конкретно с ним у вас возникла, иначе другого ответа не ждите.

Comment: Стоп! `onTouch` подходит, это я тормоз... Раньше я ловил нажатие через `onTouch`, но у него с этим косяк.

Comment: Через 4 минуты приму ответ (сайт не разрешает раньше).

Comment: @bukashka101, 4 минуты уже прошло... =)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте слушатель `OnTouchListener`, и в нем параметры `ACTION_DOWN` и `ACTION_UP`, по ним вы сможете перехватить момент нажатия/отпускания пальца. Хорошая мануалка [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/167-urok-102-touch-obrabotka-kasanija)

Comment: К сожалению, `onTouch` не то, что мне нужно (я его пробовал)...

Comment: Именно для LIstView врядли что то есть, обработчики нажатий делаются для всех компонентов как правило. Покажите, почему у вас не получилось?

Comment: Стоп! `onTouch` подходит, это я тормоз... Раньше я ловил нажатие через `onTouch`, но у него с этим косяк. Извините, но saturov ответил первым, придется принять его ответ.

Comment: да, хорошо ) рад что получилось помочь ) Хотя как я понял вы и сами были на правильном пути

Comment: Не совсем... Я только сейчас понял в чем проблема, хотя 3 дня потратил из-за такой мелочи :).